Trouble posting contents of file input to controller action using jquery in ASP.Net Core 6.0
I am attempting to post a file to a controller action in order to save it, and have run into two different problems, when using $.post to post the data as shown here:
$("#setting-form").on("submit", function(event) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  if (document.getElementById('site-error-image-input').files[0] != null) {
    var file = document.getElementById('site-error-image-input').files[0];

    formData.append("files", file);
    
    $.post("/Admin/Home/SaveSiteErrorImage/", {
      files: formData
    }, function(response) {
      var filePathInput = document.getElementsByName("Settings[64].SettingString")[0];
      filePathInput.setAttribute("value", response);
    });
  }
});


the controller action does not receive the files, and when using $.ajax to post the data like this:
$("#setting-form").on("submit", function(event) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  if (document.getElementById('site-error-image-input').files[0] != null) {
    var file = document.getElementById('site-error-image-input').files[0];
    formData.append("files", file);
    
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/Admin/Home/SaveSiteErrorImage',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    }).done(function(result) {
      if (result != '') {
        var filePathInput = document.getElementsByName("Settings[64].SettingString")[0];
        filePathInput.setAttribute("value", response);
      }
    });
  }
});


I get this JavaScript error: "Uncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData."
The controller action:
public string SaveSiteErrorImage(IList<IFormFile> files)

I tried changing the format of the post as described above, which did not work.

The parameter in the controller is "files" so it should be
formData.append("files", file);

And the $ajax settings should be
data: form,

After these modification the controller would receive files


I realize I left the wrong name for appending files when asking the question, and updated that accordingly.  I also tried your other suggestion, but it also did not work.
